# If I full format my external drive more than once it will be harder to recovery data?

Tags: format, secure-erase

With Full Format I mean unchecking the Quick Format box from the Windows format option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows XP and before: long format did not write the entire drive, only small portions of it for format purposes, so most all the data will be recoverable using software.

Windows Vista and Later versions:

> The behavior of the format command changed in Windows Vista and later Windows versions. By default in Windows Vista and later versions, the format command writes zeros to the whole disk when a full format is performed. In Windows XP and earlier versions of Windows, the format command does not write zeros to the whole disk when a full format is performed.

Once overwritten, even once, data is not recoverable, no one has ever recovered overwritten data..

[Source of Information](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/941961/change-in-the-behavior-of-the-format-command-in-windows-vista-and-late)

Comment: Nitpick, nobody without access to a clean-room with very expensive equipment has ever recovered overwritten data.  It's possible with magnetic media to use an atomic force microscope to recover after-images of previous data.  Nobody who is not seriously dealing with state-level actors actively targeting them specifically though should need to worry about this however, because it's that insanely expensive to pull off.

Comment: No one has recovered overwritten data on modern hard drives period.

Comment: Nobody has ever published anything about successfully doing it, which is not the same as nobody having ever done it.  The theory behind it is sound and has been demonstrated in other contexts, and this is not exactly something that most of the people with the funding to pull it off would be openly talking about if they did do it successfully.

Comment: Sounds like bull to me, if its never been proven........